# Program is started by Task Scheduler (in Windows 10) with '/ru SYSTEM' can't execute other programs?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I am make a simple program that can run in the background then open an URL in Windows. I use Task Scheduler to make it happens. It contains two parts: the program and and the batch file. In the program code, I am using this function to open my URL in browser:

```
func openBrowser(url string) bool {
    var args []string
    switch runtime.GOOS {
    case "darwin":
        args = []string{"open"}
    case "windows":
        args = []string{"cmd", "/c", "start"}
    default:
        args = []string{"xdg-open"}
    }

    cmd := exec.Command(args[0], append(args[1:], url)...)
    fmt.Println(cmd)
    return cmd.Start() == nil
}
```

And to run my program in background, I just create a batch file that helps me to run several commands to create a Task by the program in Task Scheduler. In the .bat file, I am using these commands:

```
schtasks /create /xml "Forward_Base.xml" /tn "Forward" /ru SYSTEM
schtasks /run /tn "Forward"
```

where Forward_Base.xml is my exported Task Scheduler file. And when I started this batch file, the task is created and run. But the command that open browser didn't work. Then, when I remove the parameter /ru SYSTEM and re-run the batch file again. My program worked, however it didn't run in the background anymore!

So my question is how did the /ru SYSTEM affect my program and how could I keep both using this feature with running openBrowser()? Thanks!

P/S: So sorry for not uploading full of the file or code in here because of security reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this. Because of some policies in Windows, when running a program in SYSTEM role, everything will execute in SYSTEM role. This means my program opens a browser, but it in another world (I notice that by checking Task Manager).

So the solution is moving my execution file to Startup folder or Windows.